# Is it possible to write identity: $(x(y^2-z^2)-y).(u(v^2-w^2)-v))=a(b^2-c^2)-b$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

Is it possible to write identity for 
$$
\{x(y^2-z^2)-y\}.\{u(v^2-w^2)-v)\}=a(b^2-c^2)-b
$$
in integers similar to the identity
$$
(x^2+y^2)(u^2+v^2)=(xu+yv)^2+(xv-yu)^2
$$
If possible, what can we choose for $a,b,c$ to be in terms of $x,y,z,u,v,w$?

Comment: It is necessary to record the identity so that the degree was equal - otherwise, the task will be different.